# Как сделать ограниченное количество знаков после запятой у вещественного числа - БЕЗ округления

Tags: python, вывод, float

Нужно сделать вывод float без округления чисел после запятой, #вводим 3.77777, выводим с тремя знаками после запятой 3.777

```py
import math
x = float(input('x: '))
print (f'Число x: {"%.3f" % (x)}')
```

Comment: А зачем тогда вообще `float`? Почему не остаться в `str`?

Comment: нужно число. Была мысль сделать строкой, потом переделать во float, но я думаю может сразу можно, тип фиксированное количество знаков после запятой не округляя

Comment: если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).

Answer (score 2):

Можно так. Грубовато, но задачу выполняет - откидываем остаток через `//`.

```
x = float(input('x: '))*1000//1/1000
print (f'Число x: {x}')
```

Comment: я где-то видел что есть такая команда для принта, которая как раз выполняет задачу. Не могу её найти, вы не слышали про такую?

Comment: Вообще никогда не интересовался форматированием вывода. Вы бы формулировали запрос тогда по-другому изначально - типа "нужен формат команды print", если это не вариант :-)

Comment: ваш вариант работает, спасибо большое. Просто интересно найти именно то самое))

Comment: Скорее всего, нет такого вывода. Он просто не нужен. Так как чаще используют вывод через строку, просто отрезая ненужные знаки. Раз вам число нужно - дал второй вариант.  
Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - можно принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).

Comment: /1000 возможно может вызвать .999999999999999999999 в некоторых случаях

Comment: @eri, а в каких именно случаях?

Answer (score 2):

```
import math
x = float(input('x: '))
print (f'Число x: {f"%.{len(str(int(x)))+3+1}s" % (x)}')
```

Comment: +1, только `str` напрягает. Там какое-то табу в вопросе на неё:-) Я сразу её предлагал - отклонили.

Comment: ну тут оно не влияет на само число, только для подсчета порядка

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто срез по строке взять

```py
>>> x = float(input('x: '))
x: 3.777777777
>>> print(f'Число x: {str(x)[:5]}')
Число x: 3.777
```

То есть `5`, это длина строки с учетом целой части, дробной и самого знака точки. Утверждение: "После запятой..." в этом случае не работает.

##### Как работать "после запятой"

Есть предложение округлить в нормальном виде и забрать всю последовательность знаков, отсекая последний

```py
>>> x = float(input('x: '))
x: 3.777777777
>>> str(round(x, 4))[:-1]
'3.777'
```

То есть: нам нужны три знака после запятой ⇒ округляем до 4 и забираем строку до предпоследнего

В данном случае вылезет не желательное поведение, если в четвертом знаке будет 0, обрежется нужное значение. Предлагаю воспользоваться функцией, чтобы исключить это поведение

```py
def floor_float(variable: float, precision: int) -> str :
    decimal_part = str(variable).split(".")[1]
    if len(decimal_part) <= precision:
        return str(variable)
    else:
        return str(round(variable, precision + 1))[:-1]
```

Tests

```py
>>> floor_float(3.77777, 4)
'3.7777'
>>> floor_float(3.777, 4)
'3.777'
>>> floor_float(3.777000000, 4)
'3.777'
>>> floor_float(3.77707, 4)
'3.7770'
```

Comment: есть функция `math.floor` чтоб не резавть round. потому как в вашем варианте обрежет лишнюю цифру если в четвертом знаке будет 0

Comment: @eri если мне не изменяет память, `floor` может резать только до целой части и не получится указать количество знаков после запятой. Если не так, поправьте. А так по делу замечание, надо пересмотреть возможность

Comment: да, прийдется умножить и поделить)

Comment: @eri никак не избавиться от этого)

Comment: посмотри другое решение обрезки с 4ым нулем

Answer (score 0):

Вот моё решение:

```
def toFixed(num, digits=3):
    i = str(num).find('.')
    digit = int(str(num)[i + digits+1])
    q = digit * 10 ** (-digits-1)
    return float(f"{num - q:.{digits}f}")
```

digits - количество цифр, которые вы хотите оставить, функция рассматривает цифру после нужной (digit), и обнуляет (num-q). Тогда когда мы возвращаем округленное число, оно по сути никогда не округлится до большего значения.

Например, num = 1.3668123, digits = 3:

```
i = 1
digit = 8
q = 0.0008
Вернется значение 1.366
```